# What is this loop condition in the solution code for the combinations problem?

Tags: java, algorithm, combinations

My confusion is regarding the following programming question:

> Given an array of size n, generate and print all possible combinations
> of r elements in array.

One of the solution programs for this question is as follows:

```
 /* arr[]  ---> Input Array 
    data[] ---> Temporary array to store current combination 
    start & end ---> Staring and Ending indexes in arr[] 
    index  ---> Current index in data[] 
    r ---> Size of a combination to be printed */
    static void combinationUtil(int arr[], int data[], int start, 
                                int end, int index, int r) 
    { 
        // Current combination is ready to be printed, print it 
        if (index == r) 
        { 
            for (int j=0; j<r; j++) 
                System.out.print(data[j]+" "); 
            System.out.println(""); 
            return; 
        } 
  
        // replace index with all possible elements. The condition 
        // "end-i+1 >= r-index" makes sure that including one element 
        // at index will make a combination with remaining elements 
        // at remaining positions 
        for (int i=start; i<=end && end-i+1 >= r-index; i++) 
        { 
            data[index] = arr[i]; 
            combinationUtil(arr, data, i+1, end, index+1, r); 
        } 
    } 
  
    // The main function that prints all combinations of size r 
    // in arr[] of size n. This function mainly uses combinationUtil() 
    static void printCombination(int arr[], int n, int r) 
    { 
        // A temporary array to store all combination one by one 
        int data[]=new int[r]; 
  
        // Print all combination using temprary array 'data[]' 
        combinationUtil(arr, data, 0, n-1, 0, r); 
    }
```

The complete code can be found [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-possible-combinations-of-r-elements-in-a-given-array-of-size-n/).

I am confused about the condition `end-i+1 >= r-index` in the function `combinationUtil` and I am struggling to understand its preceding comment:

```
    // replace index with all possible elements. The condition 
    // "end-i+1 >= r-index" makes sure that including one element 
    // at index will make a combination with remaining elements 
    // at remaining positions 
    for (int i=start; i<=end && end-i+1 >= r-index; i++) 
            { 
                data[index] = arr[i]; 
                combinationUtil(arr, data, i+1, end, index+1, r); 
            }
```

I guess the expression `r-index` is meant to check how many positions out of r have already been filled up (when `index` is 0, `r` positions are still waiting to be occupied and when `index` is 1, `r-1` of them and so on).
**I cannot wrap my head around what `end-i+1` does though.** I earlier thought it is meant to denote how far the program is in the input array through the counter/variable `i`. In other words, it wants to denote how many more items in the input array are still remaining in the array to be used. However, this idea does not make sense to me anymore.

Please explain what `end-i+1 >= r-index` means in the context of this problem.

**EDIT 1:**

I still find the use of the variables confusing. `r` is the total number of items and `index` corresponds to array indices so it will at most be 1 less than the total number. It seems weird to subtract them from one another.

**EDIT 2:**

Doesn't the expression `end-i >= r-(index+1)` make more sense? Please let me know your thoughts on this.

Answer (score 1):

It is only little optimization of code. `i` loops from `start` to `end`. In next recursion `start` is last `i + 1` of the last recursion. So elements are added to `data` in their original order.

`end - i` tells how many elements can still be used *after* current element `i`. `end - i + 1` is how many elements can be used if current element is included.

`r - index - 1` tells how many elements must still be used (because `index` starts from zero). If loop has gone so far that `data` can not be filled, there is no point to go forward. So this optimization breaks loop and backtracks.

Now it can be checked with `end - i + 1 <= r - index - 1` or `end - i + 1 < r - index`. In other words `end - i + 1 < r - index` is true there is no possible combinations. So when its negation is true loop should not be breaked `end - i + 1 >= r - index`.

EDIT:

I think `end - i + 1 >= r - index` is more clear than `end - i >= r - (index + 1)`. In above there is condition `r == index` so it makes also sense use `r - index` in below.

`end - i + 1` is like ''how many elements can be used'' and `r - index` is like ''how many elements has to be used''. If we have enough elements, then we can continue.

In `end - i >= r - (index + 1)` it is ''how many elements can be used after this one'' and ''how many elements has to be used after this one''. I personally think this is more complex. It is like skipping current step. I can see why one would prefer `r - (index + 1)` because `index` is incremented by one before comparing to `r`.

Both statements are correct and have the same result. Which one you prefer depends on your coding style. Most important thing is that you can create statement like that when you have to.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I guess the gist of your answer is `end-i+1` checks how many elements are still left in the input array to still check and `r-index` is meant to check how many positions in the target array out of `r` we still have to fill up. The condition ensures that the remaining elements in the input array are always at least equal to the number of target array positions we have to fill up.

Comment: _`end - i + 1` is like ''how many elements can be used'' and `r - index` is like ''how many elements has to be used''._ For example, if `i= 1` and `end= 2` (i.e. Input array has 2 elements), the expression `end-i+1` will give the value `2`. What does this mean? Does this mean that **BEFORE** the element at `i= 1` is used, there are 2 elements remaining to be used?  If `index=1` and r= `2` , the expression `r-index` will produce `1`.  Does this mean that **BEFORE** `index=1` is filled up in the target array, I have 1 position left to fill up?

Comment: _I can see why one would prefer `r - (index + 1)` because `index` is incremented by one before comparing to `r`._  This is exactly true. I found it strange to compare array indices with the actual array size. I did not find it intuitive.

Comment: _I found it strange to compare array indices with the actual array size._ As is being done in the expression `r-index`.